# What can I do to make Firefox updates silent?

Tags: firefox, updates

Is it possible to configure Firefox to install the updates in the background or after restart without bothering the user with notification messages?

Comment: This is already built into Firefox 15. The only prompt that is required is to restart Firefox.  Chrome has the same prompt.  Clearly its not possible to update Firefox, Chrome, or evne IE if they are running

Comment: thanks, the restart prompt wouldn't be a problem, but i guess it doesn't work without admin rights.

Comment: @KenavR: I thought this was the reason the "Mozilla Maintenance Service" was introduced. It runs with system permissions - therefore it has more privileges than an admin and could apply updates even for simple users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox 12 does that OOTB](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/24/firefox-12-has-arrived-introduces-silent-updates-for-windows-users-and-improved-developer-tools/). Apart from the UAC dialog, which you shouldn't override in another way...

Comment: Thanks, i guess i can't use the automatic update function for users without admin rights. Any other suggestion?

Comment: No, you can't. Unless you were to change the permission of all the Firefox files and registry settings, but I would advise against that.

Comment: I see that this is very old but if this is still something you'd like to do I would suggest looking at: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for silent automatic updates for the windows version, that work even if Firefox was installed by admin and is now used by restricted user:

Version 12 was supposed to be able to do this, but isn't. All it can do is display a notification. If the user clicks on that, then the update is done. But it's not done if the users don't click on the notification. And if you switch updates to silent, then the notification doesn't come, thus it's impossible to click on it.

**The latest nightly build of version 25 has just learned how do silent automatic updates, without requiring user intervention.**